# Inject service in symfony2 Controller

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection

How can I inject a service (the service that I created) into my Controller? 
A setter injection would do.

```
<?php
namespace MyNamespace;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class MyController extends Controller
{
    public function setMyService(MyService $myService)
    {
        $this->myService = $myService;
    }

    public function indexAction()
    {
        //Here I cannot access $this->myService;
        //Because the setter is not called magically!
    }
}
```

And my route settings :

```
// Resources/routing.yml
myController_index:
    pattern:  /test
    defaults: { _controller: "FooBarBundle:MyController:index" }
```

I'm setting the service in another bundle :

```
// Resources/services.yml 
parameters:
   my.service.class: Path\To\My\Service

services:
    my_service:
        class: %my.service.class%
```

When the route is resolved, the service is not injected ( I know it shouldn't ).
I suppose somewhere in a yml file, I have to set:

```
    calls:
        - [setMyService, [@my_service]]
```

I am not using this Controller as a service, it's a regular Controller that serves a Request.

Edit: At this point in time, I am getting the service with $this->container->get('my_service'); But I need to inject it.

Comment: Just use `$this->get('my_service')`

Comment: Please read the comment in this article : http://richardmiller.co.uk/2011/05/19/when-dependency-injection-goes-wrong/#comment-1301

Comment: You need to adjust your route settings. As per [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/service.html) you should have `_controller: my_service:indexAction`

Comment: my_service is another service, and it's not a Controller, hence no indexAction. indexAction belongs to MyController, which requires my_service

Comment: @Arsham My bad, you must then declare your controller as a service, as given in the documentation link.

Comment: +Brewal : Yes I have, this requires MyController to be a service, to be able to setter inject my_service.

Comment: When you do this : indexAction(Request $request){} an instance of Request is get injected into your action method, but it works only with symfony components, how can I do that with user defined services?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to inject services into your controllers, you have to [define controllers as services](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/service.html).

You could also take a look at JMSDiExtraBundle's [special handling of controllers](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSDiExtraBundle/master/usage#controllers) — if that solves your problem. But since I define my controllers as services, I haven't tried that.

Comment: It's not working (and yes, I've tried it!). The reason why is when you land on a page and it matches your route, it won't fire the service you configured, therefore it cannot see your setter and the service you try to inject.

Comment: Tried setting my Controller as a service

Comment: Then you've done it wrong. Try again. If you'll run into problems, create a separate question — we'll help you.

Comment: Thanks, my mistake was this : I kept the same format, just had change the Controller format to service format, and forgot to add Action to the method name, hence this worked : defaults: { _controller: "Name.Of.The.Service:indexAction" }

Answer (score 6):

When using the [JMSDiExtraBundle](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSDiExtraBundle/master/usage#property-injection) you **DON'T** have  to define your controller as a service (unlike @elnur said) and the code would be:

```
<?php

namespace MyNamespace;

use JMS\DiExtraBundle\Annotation as DI;
use Path\To\My\Service;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class MyController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @var $myService Service
     *
     * @DI\Inject("my_service")
     */
    protected $myService;

    public function indexAction()
    {
        // $this->myService->method();
    }
}
```

I find this approach very nice because you avoid writing a `__construct()` method.

Answer (score 3):

Since it's 2017 ending now and there is no tag for Symfony 3 or upcoming Symfony 4 (and I think there should not be), this problem is solvable in a native much better way.

If you are still struggling and somehow ended up on this page and not in Symfony docs, then you should know, that you do not need to declare controller as service, as [it is already registered as one](http://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/service.html).

What you need to do, is check you `services.yml`:

```
# app/config/services.yml
services:
    # default configuration for services in *this* file
    _defaults:
        # ...
        public: false
```

Change `public: false` to `public:true` if you want all services to be public.

Or explicitly add a service and declare it public:

```
# app/config/services.yml
services:
    # ... same code as before

    # explicitly configure the service
    AppBundle\Service\MessageGenerator:
        public: true
```

And then in your controller you can get the service:

```
use AppBundle\Service\MessageGenerator;

// accessing services like this only works if you extend Controller
class ProductController extends Controller
{
    public function newAction()
    {
        // only works if your service is public
        $messageGenerator = $this->get(MessageGenerator::class);
    }
}
```

Read more:

- [Public vs Private services](http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html#public-versus-private-services)
- [Services in Container](http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html#creating-configuring-services-in-the-container)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to define your controller as a service, you can add a listener to the *kernel.controller* event to configure it just before it is executed. This way, you can inject the services you need inside your controller using setters.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_kernel/introduction.html#component-http-kernel-kernel-controller